# Django form validation message not render in viewa in jquery ajax post

Tags: jquery, django

I have created django form and shown in the html page from django views. From the page i need to post the data from jquery ajax and i have did if data's are valid then my django valid get True and perform the task and return the json value.

But in case invalid data means it will not render to corresponding html with django error messages like normal form submission.

Is there any way to do django validation message shown in corresponding fields(as like normal django form post validation) with jquery ajax post method. Please anyone advise on, Thnaks.

Answer (score 1):

[django-ajax-validation](https://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You must render your form HTML code with render_to_string rather than render_to_response to escape and set it like a unicode string

I used to do this the BeautifulSoup HTML, XHTML and XML parser to get the exact form HTML code like this:

```
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            html = render_to_string("template.html",
            {'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))            
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
            html_form = soup.findAll('form')            
            json = simplejson.dumps({'status':True,
                'html':unicode(html_form[0]),
                'umessage':js_translators.NotifyMessage.data_saved}, ensure_ascii=False) 
            return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/json")
        else:
            html = render_to_string("template.html",
            {'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))            
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
            html_form = soup.findAll('form')            
            json = simplejson.dumps({'status':False,
                'html':unicode(html_form[0]),
                'umessage':js_translators.NotifyMessage.data_wrong}, ensure_ascii=False)
            return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/json")
```

So, at client side i'm just get the response with jQuery and Ajax and rewrite the form code with:

`$('#myform').html(response.html);`

With this I solved this problem with the django form validation with ajax